# Extra Data after last expected column, but column numbers match?

Tags: postgresql

New to importing data into Postgres, so i don't know why i'm running into these problems. I keep seeing the below error every time i try to import data from a csv file on my computer. Here's the code i'm using:

`copy data.college_stats FROM '/Users/path/All Items/Football Data/2022CFBrushingandreceiving.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV header`

and here's the error:

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY college_stats, line 2: "0,Ta'Zhawn Henry,Houston,13.0,41.0,3.2,0.0,1.0,14.0,14.0,0.0,14.0,55.0,3.9,0.0,/cfb/players/tazhawn-..."
```

here's the full line 2 referenced:

> 0, Ta'Zhawn Henry, Houston,
> 13.0,
> 41.0,
> 3.2,
> 0.0,
> 1.0,
> 14.0,
> 14.0,
> 0.0,
> 14.0,
> 55.0,
> 3.9,
> 0.0, /cfb/players/tazhawn-henry-1.html, /cfb/schools/houston/2022.html, /cfb/boxscores/2022-12-23-houston.html

Additionally, I created the initial table using the following:

```
create table data.college_stats ();

alter table data.college_stats
ADD COLUMN junk VARCHAR,
ADD COLUMN player VARCHAR,
ADD COLUMN school VARCHAR,
ADD COLUMN rush_att FLOAT,
ADD COLUMN rush_yds FLOAT,
ADD COLUMN rush_avg FLOAT,
ADD COLUMN rush_td FLOAT,
ADD COLUMN rec_yds FLOAT,
ADD COLUMN rec_avg FLOAT,
ADD COLUMN rec_td FLOAT,
ADD COLUMN total_plays FLOAT,
ADD COLUMN total_yds FLOAT,
ADD COLUMN total_avg FLOAT,
ADD COLUMN total_td FLOAT,
ADD COLUMN player_id VARCHAR,
ADD COLUMN school_id VARCHAR,
ADD COLUMN game_id VARCHAR;
```

The amount of columns match in both tables, so i can't comprehend what the problem is. Note that the error is not showing 2 of the columns because of what i'm guessing is them being too long to show, but maybe they're not being understood as new columns? They all start with a "/" but i don't know if Postgres handles that easily or not.

I've tried to choose the specific columns in the table using the code:

```
copy data.college_stats (junk, player, school, rush_att, rush_yds, rush_avg, rush_td, rec_yds, rec_avg, rec_td, total_plays, total_yds, total_avg, total_td, player_id, school_id, game_id) from '/Users/path/All Items/Football Data/2022CFBrushingandreceiving.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV header
```

But even despite naming these columns, i'm not getting any results. I was hoping this would line everything up, but it isn't. So what could the issue be?

Comment: Somewhere in the record a field is being split. To your question add the complete line 2 from the CSV file.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver added line 2 as requested

Comment: Please post the `CREATE` statement for the table `data.college_stats`.

Comment: @SebDieBln i've added the create statement, although i used an alter statement as well. let me know if you think that could be the reason for the issue.

Comment: Not that it is the cause of the issue, but why the CREATE TABLE followed by ALTER TABLE? That can all be done in one CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The amount of columns match in both tables.

That is not true. Your CREATE statement creates a table with 17 columns while your CSV file contains 18 fields. Therefore you get the error message regarding extra data after the last field.

Comment: I spent so long...and i missed such a small detail...thank you so much